# Couldn anyone provide a way to make two columnated minipages the same height?

Tags: minipage, code

So heres the code I have:

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=user/info success,frame=tlrb,label={success:userInfo}]
{
  "data":{
    "_id":{"$oid":"6042ad86c884d067744336b2"},
    "first-name":"test",
    "last-name":"test"
    },
  "message":"Successfully found user info"
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=user/info failure,frame=tlrb,label={failure:userInfo}]
{
  "data":null,
  "message":"could not parse Object ID string"
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
```

which yields the following output:

[image: Output]

Its kinda what I want, it gets the structure right, but Ideally Id want the right hand minipage to be the same size as the left hand minipage in this scenario, regardless of implementation, be it adding extra white space, or extra physical lines.

If anyone could provide some help on how to do that id appreciate it, thanks. Have a nice day.

lst configuration

```
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us the options with which you load the `listings` package.

Comment: @Mico Hello, added it to the post.

Comment: Incidentally, it is possible to specify the height of a minipage using optional arguments, but it won't do you much good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've set an option to display the captions at the bottom, I assume you'd want the listing boxes to be bottom-aligned. If this assumption is correct, you may achieve your formatting objective by changing both instances of `\begin{minipage}` to `\begin{minipage}[b]`. (`b` means "bottom alignment".)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{.47\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=user/info success,frame=tlrb,label={success:userInfo}]
{
  "data":{
    "_id":{"$oid":"6042ad86c884d067744336b2"},
    "first-name":"test",
    "last-name":"test"
    },
  "message":"Successfully found user info"
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.47\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=user/info failure,frame=tlrb,label={failure:userInfo}]
{
  "data":null,
  "message":"could not parse Object ID string"
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Mico, thats definitely an improvement, thank you very much.

Comment: @JonahFoley - If you need top alignment, just change the minipages' placement specifier from `[b]` to `[t]`.